# Serializing a Dataset in vb.net using Newtonsoft

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

All

I have a dataset with 11 Columns and 5 rows which I need to form into a json string.

The DataSet is created thus:-

```
For liCounter = 1 To liTotalCounter

If IsDBNull(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(0)) = False Then
Dim dr As DataRow = PlayerTable.NewRow()

    dr("id") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(0), Integer)
    dr("teamid") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(1), Integer)
    dr("Team_Name") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(2), String)
    dr("pno") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(3), String)
    dr("Player_Name") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(4), String)
    dr("Goals") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(6), Integer)
    dr("Games") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(5), Integer)
    dr("Assists") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(7), Integer)
    dr("Points") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(8), Integer)
    dr("Pens") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(9), Integer)
    dr("Misc") = CType(dt.Rows(liCounter).Item(10), Integer)

PlayerTable.Rows.Add(dr)

End If

Next

ds.AcceptChanges()
JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)
```

Now an example of the returned Json String is :-
"[{""id"":3,""teamid"":1,""name"":""Team 1"",""pno"":3,""name1"":""Player 1 "",""games"":2,""goals"":3,""assists"":4,""points"":5,""penalties"":8,""misc"":7},{""id"":4,""teamid"":1,""name"":""Bandit"",""pno"":7,""name1"":""Player 2"",""games"":0,""goals"":0,""assists"":0,""points"":0,""penalties"":0,""misc"":0},{""id"":5,""teamid"":1,""name"":""Bandit"",""pno"":8,""name1"":""Player 3"",""games"":0,""goals"":0,""assists"":0,""points"":0,""penalties"":0,""misc"":0},{""id"":6,""teamid"":1,""name"":""Bandit"",""pno"":9,""name1"":""Player 4 "",""games"":0,""goals"":0,""assists"":0,""points"":0,""penalties"":0,""misc"":0},{""id"":7,""teamid"":1,""name"":""Bandit"",""pno"":11,""name1"":""Player 5 "",""games"":0,""goals"":0,""assists"":0,""points"":0,""penalties"":0,""misc"":0}]"

When I go to check that the json string is valid using json checker, the error indicates that there is a problem with the string e.g.

### Parse error on line 1:
"[{""id"":3,""teamid"":1

Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'STRING'

I have tried other forms of serializing a dataset or datatable, but the same error is produced, so I have to be doing something wrong somewhere...

Any Advice would be appreciated.

-Colin

Comment: Have you tried serializing just the rows? That is what I would do since it doesn't like you care about preserving the schema information.

Comment: Not clear what you're doing here or what you expect to happen. If you want to serialize `dt`, why are you showing this `PlayerTable` and adding rows to it? What has the a DataSet to do with it? You're serializing a DataTable, apparently. -- Make sure to paste the JSON you can copy from the JSON Visualizer in Visual Studio, not the string you copy from the debugger. -- Btw, a DataSet doesn't have Columns or Rows.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have been following examples from Newtonsoft, so I will try what what you suggested.

Comment: When you say that you need to turn it into a JSON string, what's the end goal? I.e. what are you doing with that data?  It seems like you may just need to do a little string manipulation - eliminate the leading and trailing quotes, and convert all double quotes `""` into just one: `"`.  When I make those changes to your sample JSON above, VS is able to create a class from it using the Paste Special tool.